# Mysql how to stop rounding off decimals

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a database table called location it stores `latitude` and `longitude` and I used **float** as a data type, now every time I store a `latitude` and `longitude` it always round off.
For example:
When I store a `latitude` of **14.5976** it stay the same in PHPMyAdmin
but
When I store a `longitude` of **121.0176**, it round off to **121.018**.

Comment: please share table structure

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem. Does anyone have the answer? Please share.

Answer (score 3):

The float data type stores approximate values. See the following for a description.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html

For exact numbers, you want to use decimal.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html